# Display all categories (with link) of custom post type - Wordpress

Tags: php, custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

I have custom post type "case study". Inside it i have few categories.
I want to display all existing categories from this "case study" CPT.

I successfully listed items from CPT on custom archive-case-study.php, using query:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged')? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case_study',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => 1,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

and loop:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()):?>
    <div class="items">
      <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()):?>
      <?php $wp_query->the_post();?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" class="item">
          <h4 class="title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
        </a>
      <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
<?php endif ;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**Now im trying to create filters - list of all existing categories in this CPT "Case study" - i just want to list them above the "Case study" items.**

(categories should be a links to new custom archives with list of items from clicked category still in "Case study" CPT)

I have tried many options but only what i had was empty response or errors...

What code in which place should i place? I will really appreciate the answer.

Thank you!

Comment: you should be using `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query, not creating a second new query. Creating a new query breaks a lot of things such as pagination, as well as things you might not be aware of, none of which are a problem if you use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the original query. Also, CPT's don't contain categories, that doesn't make sense, do you have a custom taxonomy? Or do you refer to posts of type `case_study` as categories? This is confusing

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell for your reply! I am sorry i am not 100% sure what i am dealing with. You are right "case_study" is a post type and "category_case_study" is a taxonomy connected to this post type and this is exacly the thing i want to display as categories link filters in the front